# How to serve images with RoR API mode with Actionmailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working with a RoR API and am sending email with ruby-mailgun. While testing, I am having trouble trying to send an email with images in the email's content. My workflow is that I will send an email through the rails console to gmail and then I will check on the email in my inbox. I can view attachments but no images.

What I am trying to determine is whether this is because of api mode, a configuration change or perhaps something else entirely. Here is my development.rb configuration.

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mailgun
  config.action_mailer.mailgun_settings = {
    api_key: Rails.application.credentials.mailgun_api_key,
    domain: 'somedomain.com'
  }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'http://localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
```

And here is a snippet of the html template:

```
%div{:style => "display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;"}
  %img{:src => "#{Rails.root}/lib/assets/images/header-logo.png"}
  = image_url("/lib/assets/images/header-logo.png")
  = image_tag("header-logo.png")
```

As you can see in the div above, I have tried these three ways of rendering the assets and they still don't render in gmail. I've also swapped the `image_url` for `asset_url` and it still doesn't work. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add in your mailer, for example :

```
attachments.inline['logo.png'] = File.read('app/assets/images/logo.png')
```

and in your layout or view :

```
<%= image_tag attachments['logo.png'].url, width: "80", height: "80", border: "0" %>
```